# Vagrant + Chef: Error in provision "Shared folders that Chef requires are missing on the virtual machine."

Tags: django, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox

I've installed a Vagrant + Virtualbox using Chef (+library chef). When I do `vagrant up` first time, cookbooks get loaded correctly. However, when I do provision afterwards (be it `vagrant provision`, `vagrant reload --provision` or `vagrant up --provision`I get this error:

```
Shared folders that Chef requires are missing on the virtual machine.
This is usually due to configuration changing after already booting the
machine. The fix is to run a `vagrant reload` so that the proper shared
folders will be prepared and mounted on the VM.
```

I searched everywhere and the only solution given is to do `vagrant reload --provision`, this worked up up to Vagrant 1.3.1.

Answer (score 106):

it seems like there is a bug with sync folders, this clears the cache and fixed it for me. (from your project directory)

```
rm .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/synced_folders
vagrant reload --provision
```

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5199

EDIT: this [should be fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/300b9c910954bf0e6beed0888e121473639ef2c8) in vagrant `1.7.4`

Answer (score -3):

That's a fairly common issue with the Vagrant plugins for both Berkshelf and Librarian. Just get used to running that command.

The way to avoid it is to use something like Test-Kitchen instead of the Vagrant plugins. That isn't a drop-in replacement though.

Comment: "Just get used to running that command" - The OP states that the command doesn't work, so that doesn't help.

Comment: `vagrant reload --provision` will generally fix it, sometimes taking a few tries to fully converge.